# Google AdSense bot's algorithm and behavior

Tags: google, google-adsense, googlebot

I am interesting in Google AdSense bot's algorithm and behavior with web site. I did not work with AdSense and I do not have account. So I need your help to understand:

1) Google's bot from time to time downloads all pages from web site. Am I right?

2) Google's bot does not understand dynamic content (loaded by Ajax). So I must generate static content and return it within HTML page and this pages must show identical content for all users and for Google bot?

3) Because of (1) and (2) I cannot use only root path `http://example.com` with some "main" widget. I must generate unique pages for example `http://example.com/thread?id=101`?

4) Gbot downloads pages (1) for grabbing (indexing) keywords from them and then store (on it's servers) these information for example by key/value (where key is page path, value is tag cloud). Am i right?

5) When web site has been opened in browser by user. Integrated HTML AdSense's code loads some JavaScript. As I understand by "Googling" this JavaScript do not index page, but makes call (with some parameter key==page_path) to Google's server and gets appropriate ad links. Then shows this ad links in it's frame. Is it right behavior? Maybe JavaScript makes some local indexing of page's content?

6) How Google's bot and AdSense's JavaScript work with cookies? As I understand AdSense can use cookies for show appropriate ad links. If it is right, please give me some use cases;)

I know that "true" algorithm is known only by engineers from Google. But some of you had experience with AdSense and AdSense HTML/JavaScript. Please correct my vision of it;)

Thank you very much for any advice!!!

P.S. This question is very important for me. It is not some question for fun! So Please do not close it;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered here.
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9627/google-adsense-bots-algorithm-and-behavior